# Angular 2 router.navigate not working inside nested js function

Tags: angular, typescript

Given the app module:

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule }   from '@angular/router';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent }        from './app.component';
import {DashboardComponent} from "./components/dashboard/dashboard.component";
import {LogoutComponent} from "./components/logout/logout.component";
import {LoginComponent} from "./components/login/login.component";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {PrescribeComponent} from "./components/prescribe/prescribe.component";
//import { HeroService }         from './hero.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'logout',
        component: LogoutComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'prescribe',
        component: PrescribeComponent
      }

    ])
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    LogoutComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    PrescribeComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    //HeroService
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Given the following component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
declare var ExternalJS: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/login/login.component.tpl.html',
})
export class LoginComponent {

  public redirect;
  public username: string;
  public password: string;

  constructor(public _router: Router) {

    this.username = 'someUsername';
    this.password = 'SomePassword';


  }
  doLogin() {

    var self = this;

    ExternalJS.authenticateByUser({username: this.username, password: this.password}, (response => {


     self._router.navigate(['/dashboard']);


    }));
  }

}
```

It navigates to dashboard, but the dashboard route disappears in the url.

So I am left with : http://localhost:3001/ Where I should see http://localhost:3001/dashboard.

If I move the self._router.navigate(['/dashboard']); outside of the js function, it works fine.

UPDATE:

Doing the route change outside of the function works fine :( But i need it in the callback of the JS function.

```
 doLogin() {

    var self = this;
    self.goToRoute(); //MOVED TO HERE. WORKING FINE.

    /*ExternalJS.authenticateByUser({username: this.username, password: this.password}, ((response:any) => {   

           self.goToRoute();
         })


    }));*/
  }
```

UPDATE 3:

Got it working based on Gunter Comments:

```
doLogin() {

    ExternalJs.authenticateByUser({username: this.username, password: this.password}, (response => {
      var self = this;
      ExternalJs.setUser(12398787, "user1", function () {
        ExternalJs.subscribeEvent({
          eventName: 'user.select',
          callback: (data => {
            self.zone.run(() => {
              self._router.navigate(['./dashboard']);
            });
          })
        });
      });
    }));
  }
```

UPDATE 4: 
The hash was still dissappearing event after adding zone. I added this to app module:

```
providers: [
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
  ]
```

, and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Whats your routing setup  ?

Comment: UPPATE 4: 
The hash was still dissappearing event after adding zone. I added this to app module: 
providers: [
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
  ],

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to ensure the code is executed within Angulars zone, otherwise change detection won't run and this causes `router.navigate()` not to work as expected:

```
constructor(public _router: Router, private zone:NgZone) {
```

```
ExternalJS.authenticateByUser({username: this.username, password: this.password}, (response => {
  this.zone.run(() =>  
    this._router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
  });
}));
```

If you use `=>` there is no need for `self`

Comment: Gunter, this goes the route. I see /dashboard for a second, then while it is staying on /dashboard, the route switched to /login, but its still on dashboard

Comment: I don't know what's ging on in your app. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: Gunter I added my app module with routes

Comment: If I do this outside of the JS stuff, it works fine: this._router.navigate(['/dashboard']); but I need it in the JS callback

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to resolve by creating this:

```
 goToRoute(){

    this._router.navigate(['/dashboard']);

  }
```

Then:

```
ExternalJS.authenticateByUser({username: this.username, password: this.password}, (response => {
  self.goToRoute()
}));
```